# How to perform orientation constrained based Inverse Kinematics in trac_ik

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, baxter, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default KDL IK solver is still not robust enough. Hence I am planning to use [trac_ik](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik).

Instead of keeping the orientation constant throughout the trajectory, I want it to change within specified limits. My question is how to perform orientation constrained based Inverse Kinematics in trac_ik?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254942/how-to-perform-orientation-constrained-based-inverse-kinematics-in-trac_ik/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just asked the maintainer on your behalf, who said:

You can't do orientation constraints with the moveit plugin, only when you're using [trac_ik_lib](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/HEAD/trac_ik_lib/) directly. As outlined at the bottom of the README, you can specify an orientation (and position) *tolerance* in the `KDL::Twist` message provided to `ik_solver.CartToJnt(...)`, which are `+/-` symmetric.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-06**:
Can you please answer a related question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/293356/unit-for-the-bounds-of-the-ik-call-in-trac_ik_python/)?